# Meson cannot find package, but pc file is where all others are found?

Tags: c++, package, pkg-config, conan, meson-build

Currently I am getting this error trying to compile with meson:

`../meson.build:96:0: ERROR: Dependency "cereal" not found, tried pkgconfig and cmake`

However, the `cereal.pc` file is located on the build directory where about a 12 more `pc` files are found (dependencies are downloaded through conan). Every other pc file in the directory is found:

```
Dependency vulkan found: YES 1.2.162 (cached)
Dependency vulkan-memory-allocator found: YES 2.3.0 (cached)
Dependency glfw3 found: YES 3.3.4 (cached)
Dependency threads found: YES unknown (cached)
Dependency zlib found: YES 1.2.11 (cached)
Dependency shaderc found: YES 2019.0 (cached)
Dependency freetype2 found: YES 2.10.4 (cached)
Dependency stb found: YES 20200203 (cached)
Dependency tinygltf found: YES 2.5.0 (cached)
Dependency eigen3 found: YES 3.3.9 (cached)
Found pkg-config: /usr/bin/pkg-config (0.29.2)
Found CMake: /usr/bin/cmake (3.18.4)
Run-time dependency cereal found: NO (tried pkgconfig and cmake)

../meson.build:106:0: ERROR: Dependency "cereal" not found, tried pkgconfig and cmake
```

As mentioned, the file is in the same place as all others and at the same directory level.
The name of the pc file is indeed `cereal.pc` and this is what the file looks like:

```
prefix=/home/makogan/.conan/data/cereal/1.3.0/_/_/package/5ab84d6acfe1f23c4fae0ab88f26e3a396351ac9
libdir=${prefix}/lib
includedir=${prefix}/include

Name: cereal
Description: Serialization header-only library for C++11.
Version: 1.3.0
Libs: -L"${libdir}" -Wl,-rpath,"${libdir}"
Cflags: -I"${includedir}"
```

The path specified in there does exist and the files found inside the repo seem to be correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Removing all meson files through `rm -rf meson*` inside the build directory and recompiling seems to have fixed the problem.